# How to update macOS to latest release of current version?

Tags: software-update

I am on Catalina 10.15.3 and do not want to move to Big Sur just yet. Software Update does have the option to update to Big Sur but I am unable to determine how to do just a minor point update.  How do I install the latest update of Catalina?

**Update** From a comment by @jefe2000 I am trying the command line version and it seems promising.

```
$/usr/sbin/softwareupdate -l
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update- 
    Title: macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update, Version:  , Size: 5099042K, Recommended: YES, Action: restart,
```

But what is the actual label?  I was unable to get this to work and have created a separate question for it.  [Unable to install an update via the softwareupdate command line tool](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414557/unable-to-install-an-update-via-the-softwareupdate-command-line-tool)

Comment: Are you sure you are not already at the most recent version of Catalina?

Comment: I updated the question with my current version - apologies for the omission.

Comment: The command line version of macOS software updater — `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate` — has the capability to ignore specified updates. Using this, you could tell it to ignore the Big Sur updates and install any other available updates. Would this achieve what you're going for?

Comment: @jefe2000  thanks that looks v promising.  I updated the question: the label to be used is very unclear.

Comment: @jefe2000  Please go ahead and make an answer.  I don't have `softwareupdate` working yet but have made that a separate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and install the [Catalina 10.15.7 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2052?locale=en_GB) from Apple.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer and I have upvoted. There is another one about performing from the command line. I will wait to decide which to award based on if I can get that other to work

Comment: This is by far the easiest way. I was about to add this as a comment to your previous question but you deleted it before I could hit Enter.

Comment: The command line version in the end is difficult to use and did not work. Just download the dmg is the better approach.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I had thought I had accepted it 12 hours ago

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install the update with the following:

`softwareupdate --install "macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update" --restart`

Answer (score 1):

The command line version of the macOS software update — `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate` — has the capability to ignore specified updates. The `--ignore` command line option performs the functionality.

From the `sofwareupdate` man page:

> ```
> --ignore identifier ...
>     Manages the per-machine list of ignored updates.
>     The identifier is the first part of the item name (before
>     the dash and version number) that is shown by --list.
> ```

Using this, you could tell the software updater to ignore the Big Sur updates and install any other available updates.

Comment: I do not actually want to use `--ignore` : please remove that or provide proper context.  I: will award this for pointing the right direction - but the specific command is still TBD (see the lnked question)