# Unable to install an update via the softwareupdate command line tool

Tags: command-line, software-update

I am trying to install a macOS update from the  command line. Let's see what updates are available:

```
$/usr/sbin/softwareupdate -l
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
* Label: macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update- 
    Title: macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update, Version:  , Size: 5099042K, Recommended: YES, Action: restart,
```

But what is the actual label? According to this resource https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/update-macos-terminal-command/ it is the exact wording:

[image]

So the analogous value here would be *macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update-* . However that does not work:

```
 $/usr/sbin/softwareupdate -i "macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update-"
Software Update Tool

macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update-: No such update
No updates are available.
```

I also tried some variants:

```
(python39) 10:25:21/~ $/usr/sbin/softwareupdate -i "macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update"
Software Update Tool

macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update: No such update
No updates are available.

$/usr/sbin/softwareupdate -i "macOS Catalina 10.15.7"
Software Update Tool

macOS Catalina 10.15.7: No such update
No updates are available.
```

So then how is the softwareupdate tool supposed to be used ?

Comment: I don't know whether it makes any difference but if I read `man softwareupdate` then examples provided there don't include quotation marks.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg  That does not work: each of the space separated tokens is treated as a separate installation request.  The `man` is incorrect.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg The example in the man page doesn't have spaces in the tag. The quotes are required by the shell to ensure that the whole tag is read as one argument.

Comment: Simply said you need `sudo` to install software via `softwareupdate`. The error message isn't really helpful though.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks, it makse sense. However, does it mean that this part of man is also incorrect: `item ... One or more specified updates. The --list output shows the item names you can specify here, prefixed by the * or - characters

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Yeah, it's not really clear that the "Label:" part should be omited.

Comment: The blog *did* include the  "Update-" at the end.

Comment: I had also tried with `sudo` and it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As of Sept 2021, when attempting an upgrade to Catalina 10.15.7...

I ran into the same problems as OP but was forced to modify my solution from accepted answer.

No amount of the following made a difference on their own. The result was always the same.

- sudo
- /usr/sbin
- Label v Title name

---

### The Fix

This is the line that eventually worked for me:
`sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -ia 'macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update'`

##### Breakdown of CLI

- `sudo` I threw this in even though I'm running as system. It worked.
- `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate` proper shell pathing should void the need to add the path, but multiple forums suggested otherwise. So, it didn't hurt to add and it worked
- `-ia` ... WTF? `-i` is for install... so that's good. `-a` is for all available... see below
- `'this is the actual Title of the update, not the label'`: To get this, I run `softwareupdate -l | grep Title`. Then I pull out the title from the other info

### This is Stupid & Broken

Yes. The Fix worked. But... why was it necessary to use the `-a` flag? That's expressly saved for installing all available updates. However, when running this command, it only installed the targeted update and left the BigSur update uninstalled.

Apple has clearly broken something in the tool, and it seems with the impending MDM restrictions and deprecation in macOS Big Sur, has no intention of fixing this.

I hope this works for you before Apple sunsets remote administration completely.

Comment: I cant' really test this but will assume it is correct since you have clearly read and understood the other answers .  So the assumption will be that you have a valid "update" to the accepted answer.  If any reader tries this please do comment to let us know how this answer is doing relative to the one from @nohillside

Comment: @WestCoastProjects... understood and appreciated. And yes, FWIW, this was tested. I didn't want to have to write this answer or test this solution. I would have been very content if the approved answer was correct.  I also have no doubt that this answer will need to be updated for specific versions of MacOS as their rollback of remote administration support grows with each new release, preferring to NUDGE users and rollout policies with MDM.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the man page you need to use `sudo` to actually install software via `softwareupdate`. So in your case it's

```
sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -i "macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update"
```

to install 10.15.7, or

```
sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -ia
```

to install all available updates.

Comment: I am interested to install a specific update.

Comment: But .. I can't find a working solution and will give this a roll anyways..

Comment: @StephenBoesch You only seem to have one pending so it doesn't matter. But try with `sudo` and the label `macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update`.

Comment: Too late "Cannot cancel updates after installation has started."  ;)

Comment: fyi after shutdown and restart the update did not work. I am way out of time to deal with this and will bite the bullet to upgrade to `Big Sur`.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the CLI version only requests the delta. See your other question, get the combo.

Comment: I regret to inform you that in Big Sur, `softwareupdate` is not allowed to install system updates, although it apparently can do others. It will download it. It will reboot. But it will not actually install. I found this out the hard way. (That _may_ only be for Apple Silicon Macs, I'm not 100% sure and google was no help. Everyone is talking about `--ignore` being deprecated so the search results are full of that.)

Comment: @TJLuoma It took way too much Googling to find this out. Thank you.

Comment: @KevinHernandez it's such a dumb decision / change my Apple. I don't understand it at all. Makes no sense at all… and _pretending_ to do it (and then fail) is definitely the worst way to no longer support this. Just so dumb.